# Is there a way to track which assembly definition a script belongs to?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I upgraded my project to Unity 2021 and have tons of the same error:

> error CS0246: The type or namespace name  could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

This is for both packages and my own scripts. I added an assembly definition in my main scripts folder and tried to add a reference but I couldn't find the proper one to fix any issue.

For example, I'm using the RootMotion FinalIK and PuppetMaster assets. All scripts referencing these have `using RootMotion.FinalIK` and using `RootMotion.Dynamics` However, the script doesn't recognize RootMotion.Dynamics and every variable type using RootMotion.FinalIK cannot be found.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The fix was to just restart Unity and VSCode.